# Updating site content after an AJAX call without a page reload

Tags: functions, ajax

I've created this PHP function that deletes a product with an id passed by an AJAX call:

```
function deleteSelectedProduct() 
{
   if ( isset($_POST['productToDelete']) && ! empty($_POST['productToDelete']) ) {
     $postId=$_POST['productToDelete'];
     wp_delete_post($postId);
    }
   die();
}
```

My AJAX call looks like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        data: sampleData,
        type: 'POST',
        url: AjaxObject.ss_ajax_url,
        success: function(msg) {
            window.location.reload(true);
        }               
    });
```

As you can see, I perform a page reload with `window.location.reload(true);` in order to refresh a list of products on a page (since a product has just been deleted).

Is there a straightforward way to update the page's content without a page reload?

One of the solutions I thought about would be amending the PHP scrips so that it uses output buffering:

```
function deleteSelectedProduct() 
{
   if ( isset($_POST['productToDelete']) && ! empty($_POST['productToDelete']) ) {
     $postId=$_POST['productToDelete'];
     wp_delete_post($postId);
    }

   ob_start();
   include 'some_page.php';
   $response = ob_clean();
   echo $response;
   die();
}
```

I am not sure if this is the way to go. I would appreciate your advice.

Comment: If you're products have ID's then you can target them. What I normally do is create ID's that like `id="product-[id]"` where [id] is the post ID. Then you can remove the element with your JS.

Comment: Yes, there is a straightforward way, it is using AJAX. In short, you could just replace the product list container content after deletion via AJAX with the up-to-date state of that list, no need to reload the page. Or you delete the list element like  @kel suggested.

Comment: both solutions above are good. $('#product_container').replaceWith(response) is how you could do @ialocin's suggestion.

Comment: @shahar `$('#product_container').replaceWith(response)` would only work if the response was the updated HTML for that part of the page. The script to which my AJAX sends a request does not return any markup. It performs only a deletion. I will need to design the script so that it returns the updated markup, or go with @kel's method.

Comment: Of course, I was just illustrating how @ialocin's suggestion could be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use the product id as a classname in your html and then you could do:

```
$.ajax({
    data: sampleData,
    type: 'POST',
    url: AjaxObject.ss_ajax_url,
    success: function(msg) {
        $( '.product-' + sampleData.productToDelete ).remove();
    }               
});
```

If you have any counts on the page you would need to figure that out as well. Also if you have pagination thats not generated via some javascript framework then your best bet is to just continue reloading the page as needed.

Comment: This will definitely do the job. Thanks for this suggestion.